# How to fix the following procedures so that the parameters act as in out mode parameters?

Tags: arrays, binary, ada

Please solve this in ADA:

```
        --initialize first array (My_Array) with random binary values
    procedure Init_Array (Arr : BINARY_ARRAY) is
        package Random_Bit is new Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random (BINARY_NUMBER);
        use Random_Bit;
        G : Generator;
    begin
        Reset (G);
        for Index in 1..16 loop
            Arr(Index) := Random(G); 
        end loop;
    end Init_Array;

        --reverse binary array
    procedure Reverse_Bin_Arr (Arr : BINARY_ARRAY) is
        hold : BINARY_ARRAY := Arr;
    begin
        for Index in 1..16 loop
            Arr(15 - Index) := hold(Index);
        end loop;
    end Reverse_Bin_Arr;
```

```
   --initialize first array (My_Array) with random binary values
   procedure Init_Array (Arr: in out BINARY_ARRAY);

   --reverse binary array
   procedure Reverse_Bin_Arr (Arr : in out BINARY_ARRAY);
```

I believe my above procedures are correct. I just keep getting the following error:
assgn.adb:7:15: not fully conformant with declaration at assgn.ads:7
assgn.adb:7:15: mode of "Arr" does not match
assgn.adb:19:15: not fully conformant with declaration at assgn.ads:10
assgn.adb:19:15: mode of "Arr" does not match
gnatmake: "assgn.adb" compilation error

The first procedure should initialize a random array that houses each bit of a binary number. Example: [1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0]

The second procedure should reverse the bits in the binary array.

Answer (score 4):

The error `not fully conformant with declaration` means exactly what it says; there's a mismatch between the spec and the implementation

The specification says (notice the `in out` parameter mode):

```ada
   procedure Init_Array (Arr: in out BINARY_ARRAY);
```

but the implementation defaults to `in`:

```ada
    procedure Init_Array (Arr : BINARY_ARRAY) is
```

Comment: It is also possible to treat the parameter to Init_Array as an OUT parameter since the object is to only assign values to the parameter. The procedure Reverse_Bin_Array must use an IN OUT parameter because the result depends upon the initial values of the parameter.